# In a Java class, I can see that a class object and variable can have same name. Which value will be printed if they have same scope?

Tags: java, oop

```
public class Simple { 
    public float price; 
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        Simple price = new Simple (); 
        price.price = 4;
        System.out.println(price);
    } 
}
```

What should be the output and why ? The object value or 4.0 ?

Comment: Um. Why don't you run it and find out?

Comment: An IDE is your guy in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please familiarize yourself with these docs - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

They do not have the same scope (or thay would be the same variable). The variable with the *narrowest* scope that still encloses the usage is the one used.

```
public static class Simple {

    public float price;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Narrower scope than the instance variable.
        Simple price = new Simple();
        price.price = 4;
        // Uses the narrower one (the Price, not the float).
        System.out.println(price);
    }
}
```

Output

```
com.oldcurmudgeon.test.Test$Simple@15db9742
```

Comment: This is probably the only answer that actually answers the question that should have been asked: "The output is X, but why?"

Answer (score 1):

> What should be the output and why ?  The object value or 4.0 ?

The object value ... because within the `main` method the local variable `price` will hide the instance variable `price`.

(In fact, the `println` method calls `toString()` on the object and prints the resulting string.  But I guess you knew that.)

> In a Java class, I can see that a class object and variable can have same name. Which value will be printed if they have same scope?

That doesn't make sense in the context of your example, because the local variable and the instance variable *don't* have the same scope.

(And what is more, even if the instance field `price` wasn't hidden, you still would not be able to print it with `System.out.println(price);`  because you can't refer to an instance variable like that in a `static` method.  You can't refer to `this` in a `static` method, either implicitly or explicitly.)

Comment: Got it Thanks Stephen :)

Answer (score 0):

Because price is the reference variable **declared in your main method scope** unlike  `float price` that is declared in the `Simple` class scope as instance variable.

If you add a `System.out.println(price);` in your `Simple` constructor for example it must print **4.0** because he looks for the variable reference declared there.